# Texturing a table made of wooden planks

Tags: texturing

I want to model a set of tables of the E15 brand. They make their tables by taking an oak tree and sawing this tree in wooden planks and then they make their tables with these wooden planks. Like in this image.

[image]

I am trying to understand how to texture this table. Each wooden plank has its own natural characteristic texture and no plank is the same. It is the wood of the tree and they oiled that. I was thinking of partitioning this object in Edit mode in "planks" and assigning a different texture to each partition (wooden plank) of the mesh. Is that a good idea?

But how to create these textures. Should I go for procedural textures ? Because it is not easy to find those real life textures in all their variations.

I hope this is a good question. It is always hard to tell what you can ask here and how to formulate your question.

Comment: I guess a real image would be the best, but you could recreate this kind of material with Noise for example, you should precise what your preference is. Also does it need to be seamless? Because I guess there's no continuity between the perpendicular sides?

Comment: The short sides of the tabletop have a completely different texture than the long sides of the tabletop and also the top view shows a lot of different textures. This the variety natures comes with and how to solve that with digital textures ?

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar things with CC0 image textures like these:
https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures?search=&resolution=1&category=Wood&color=any&page=1

If you have, for example, 5 planks in an image, you can flip them on the X, Y, or both axes for a total of 20 'unique' plank textures.  Unique in the sense that you can trick the eye by randomizing the order and making sure two similar planks aren't right next to each other.